# Why does RMarkdown `render` behavior depend on whether it's called from RStudio Server or from a PHP shell?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I have an RMarkdown document that includes 'special characters', such as `ë`. If I render the document using RStudio Server's "knit document" button, it renders fine. When I render it by using the RStudio Server button to source another R script that calls `RMarkdown`'s `render` function, it also renders fine.

However, from some reason that's beyond me (but hopefully not for long), I get different results when that same R script is called by `index.php` using:

```
$results = shell_exec("R --file='/home/username/public_html/some/subdirectories/process.R' --no-save 2>&1");
```

When I do this, in the resulting .html file, the special symbols (I guess the unicode symbols) are replaced by `<U+00EB>`. I've tried to look up whether this is some kind of variation of HTML elements that I didn't know about yet, but I have been unable to find anything about this.

(note: any link to a place where I can learn more about this (and, while we're at it, why my browser doesn't show it as, for example, the ë it represents, is also greatly appreciated!)

---

**Reproducable example**

*Contents of `example.php`:*

```
<?php
  shell_exec("R --file='/home/username/public_html/subdirectory/example.R' --no-save 2>&1");
?>
```

*Contents of `example.R` (this is what I needed on my server):*

```
workingPath <- "/home/username/public_html/subdirectory";

### Set path to RStudio's pandoc version
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),
                      "/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc",
                      sep=":"));

### Set HOME and LANG
Sys.setenv(HOME = '/home/username');
Sys.setenv(LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8');

require(rmarkdown);

renderResults <-
  render(file.path(workingPath, 'example.Rmd'),
         output_file = file.path(workingPath, 'example.html'),
         intermediates_dir = file.path(workingPath, 'tmp'),
         encoding="UTF-8");
```

*Contents of `example.Rmd`:*

````
---
title: 'Reproducable example'
output: html_document
---

```{r}
  cat("This is an ë symbol.");
```
````

---

*Results of this example:*

When I run this from R Studio, I get:

> cat("This is an ë symbol.");
>
> ## This is an ë symbol.

When I run this from PHP, I get:

> cat("This is an ë symbol.");
>
> ## This is an <U+00EB> symbol.

(note how, interestingly, the `echo`'ed ë does show up normally...)

---

I now resorted to doing a `str_replace` in the `index.php` file, but that's not ideal.

I've checked the `render` manual, but I can't find anything about this behavior.

I've also looked at specifying options for `pandoc` in the YAML header of the .Rmd file, but the only thing that seems to come close is the [`--ascii` option](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#reader-options), and that doesn't do anything. The [R Studio RMarkdown page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html) doesn't provide any hints, either.

Could it perhaps have to do with environment variables that are set in RStudio? I already had to set:

```
Sys.setenv(HOME = '/home/oupsyusr');
Sys.setenv(LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

in the R script to get Pandoc going in the first place when called in the R script called from the PHP shell; but if this is the problem, how can I figure out which settings RStudio sets to which values, or more accurately, which of those are important? I ran:

```
Sys.getenv()
```

From within R Studio, and that shows quite a list. I recognize none of the entries as having to do with encoding or so.

Or, does knitr cause this? When I store and inspect the .md file, the Unicode element things already show up. However, the [knitr help page with chunk options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) doesn't say anything about unicode or encoding in general.

Does anybody know where this is documented, or does anybody happen to have encountered this situation before?

I'm running RStudio 0.99.903 and R 3.3.1 on CentOS 6.8.

Comment: What's the output of `Sys.getlocale("LC_ALL")` in each case? It's possible that the R session believes it's running in a non UTF-8 locale in the PHP case; if that's the issue then it's possible that R is discovering unicode characters that cannot be represented in the system locale, and so just printing a unicode code point representation instead.

Comment: @KevinUshey, this seems spot on! From RStudio, the locale is often set to 'en_US.UTF-8' and only sometimes to 'C' ([the default apparently](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html)). From PHP, it's only set to C. When I call:


`Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL', "en_US.UTF-8");`


It works! Thank you!!! It's always satisfying to solve something after hours of frustration :-) Can you change your comment into an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Yeah `<U+XXXX>` is often an indication of locale problems, and the `C` locale is often the culprit on Linux.

Comment: This is great, thank you! Regarding `<U+XXXX>` more generally, in case anybody else stumbles upon this answer: in Windows, I incidentally had the same problem when trying to save a file using `cat` to a `file` connection where I had specified `encoding='UTF-8'`. Using `writeLines` with `useBytes=TRUE` solved that instance. Apparently, when working in R, sometimes you want to prevent specifying the encoding exactly because you use e.g. `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, issues of this form (where unicode characters are converted to a unicode code point representation, e.g. `<U+00EB>` in this case) are caused by an attempt to run R within a non-UTF-8 locale.

Typically, this can be verified by checking the output of `Sys.getlocale("LC_ALL")`. If you see a `C` locale reported, then you likely need to enforce a UTF-8 locale with something like:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")
```

substituting the particular UTF-8 locale flavor based on your desired language. (For reference, the set of available locales can usually be queried from a terminal with something like `locale -a`).